# Comprobar elementos de un array y generar codigo sin repeticion

Tags: php

tengo la siguiente array:

```
$array = array(1234,2545,6978,3144,9647,5254,2547);
```

Y tengo una funcion que me genera un codigo aleatorio de 4 digitos. 
Me gustaria saber como comprobar que el codigo de 4 digitos no se encuentre en el array y generarlo.

Estoy intentando usar el siguiente

```
function RandomStringN($length){
      $characters = '123456789';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i<$length; $i++) { $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)]; } return $randomString;
}
$cod = RandomStringN(4);
$array = array(2245,2545,2247,3471,2578,3658,1425);    
if(in_array($cod,$array)){
            $cod = $this->RandomStringN(4);
        }
echo $cod;
```

Eventualmente me repite el codigo. Teniendo en cuenta que los elementos del array son mas de 5mil

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograrlo con `in_array` asi:

```
$array = array(1234,2545,6978,3144,9647,5254,2547);
if (in_array(2545, $array) {
  //el elemento existe en el array
} else {
  //el elemento no se encuentra en el array
}
```

Comment: Lo intente pero de igual forma evetualmente me repite crea un codigo que ya se encuentra dentro del array, existira alguna otra forma?